# Display upTime using `millis()` - Arduino Uno

Tags: millis

I want to use the following function to display MCU's uptime, but after several hours I get error.

```
void uptime(char *ret_clk)
{
  byte days = 0;
  byte hours = 0;
  byte minutes = 0;
  byte seconds = 0;

  int sec2minutes = 60;
  int sec2hours = (sec2minutes * 60);
  int sec2days = (sec2hours * 24);

  unsigned long time_delta = millis() / 1000UL;

  days = (int)(time_delta / sec2days);
  hours = (int)((time_delta - days * sec2days) / sec2hours);
  minutes = (int)((time_delta - days * sec2days - hours * sec2hours) / sec2minutes);
  seconds = (int)(time_delta - days * sec2days - hours * sec2hours - minutes * sec2minutes);

  sprintf(ret_clk, "%01dd %02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

after 2:55 hours I got a correct answer : `0d 02:55:27`

also after 4 hours, a correct answer : `0d 04:06:44`

but roughly after 12 hours i get an error: `1d 02:01:27`

and after roughly 20 hours I get : `2d 23:74:26`

What is wrong in `uptime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an 8-bit Arduino an `int` can only hold values in the range -32768 to +32767. One day's worth of seconds is 86400, which is far outside that range.

You should replace your `sec2...` variables with literals, maybe `#define`d - and don't forget to force the length for longer values:

```cpp
#define SEC2MINUTES 60
#define SEC2HOURS 3600
#define SEC2DAYS 86400UL
```

Comment: what is the bennefit define it using `#define` ? whould define as `usgined long` save the problem ?

Comment: @Guy.D If you put it in a variable and use that variable to calculate other variables to do your calculations with it has to calculate them every single iteration. By using #define (or you could use `const unsigned long` if you wish) it calculates it at compile time (which I shortcut by just calculating it myself).

Comment: what might be that cause getting this result :`upTime[0d 10:123:33]` ? code was corrected as you suggested

Answer (score 3):

The millis function increments rapidly, hence it easily exceeds the maximum value of int -  -32768 to +32767.

So, use unsigned long data types for millis and other stuff that's large.

4 billion and some change is the max value that unsigned long data types can store, hence no overflowing till about 49 days.